# SwiftUI ScrollViewReader ScrollTo Exhibiting Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

I've tested this in Xcode and Playgrounds and I am finding consistent, unexpected results. In the code below, what I'd expect is that every time the button is pushed the ScrollView goes to the bottom of the text. scrollTo seems to show different behavior whether the source text is a var or a string of some length. The goal is to comment out Options 1, 2, and 3 and have the end of the string show on screen every time the button is pressed. This does not work. If Options 2 and 4 are uncommented, the bottom of the ScrollView is shown, as expected. If only Options 2 and 4 are uncommented (removing a single \n) then the bottom of ScrollView is not shown. How do I change this code so that only option 4 is uncommented and pressing the button always goes to the end of the ScrollView?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textFruit = ""
    var stringArray = ["Apples\n\n", "Pears\n\n", "Strawberries\n\n", "Kiwi\n\n", "Blueberries\n\n"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ScrollView{
                    //Option 1
                    //Text("Top\n\nThis\n\nIs\n\nA\n\nHorizontally\n\nVery\n\nLong\n\nString\n\nThat\n\nGoes\n\nFrom\n\nThe\n\nTop\n\nOf\n\nThe\n\nScreen\n\nTo\n\nThe\n\nBottom\n\nOf\n\nThe\n\nScreen\n\nBottom")
                    //Option 2
                   // Text("Top\n\nThis\n\nIs\n\nA\n\nHorizontally\n\nVery\n\nLong\n\nString\n\nThat\n\nGoes\n\nFrom\n\nThe\n\nTop\n\nOf\n\n")
                    //Option 3
                    Text("Top\n\nThis\n\nIs\n\nA\n\nHorizontally\n\nVery\n\nLong\n\nString\n\nThat\n\nGoes\n\nFrom\n\nThe\n\nTop\n\nOf\n")
                    //Option 4
                    Text(textFruit)
                    Spacer(minLength: 60)
                        .id("bottom")
                        .onChange(of: textFruit){_ in   value.scrollTo("bottom")
                        }
                }
            }
            
            
            Button(action: {
                textFruit += stringArray.randomElement() ?? ""
            }, label: {
                Text("Add Word")
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Below you can see options 2 and 4 uncommented and the text is scrolling as anticipated. [Correct Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oukaZ.png)

With options 3 and 4 only uncommented, pressing the button does not show the last fruit on the list.
[Not Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POYgj.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try smth like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
struct Record: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    let text: String

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

@State var textFruit = ""
@State var source: [Record] = []

var stringArray = ["Apples\n\n", "Pears\n\n", "Strawberries\n\n", "Kiwi\n\n", "Blueberries\n\n"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
                ScrollView{
                    ForEach(source) { record in
                        Text(record.text)
                            .id(record.id)
                    }

                    Spacer(minLength: 60)
                        .id("bottom")
                        .onChange(of: source) { value in
                            scrollReader.scrollTo("bottom")
                        }
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                if let element = stringArray.randomElement() {
                    source.append(Record(text: element))
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Add Word")
            })

            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

}

If it required to have just `Text` - just replace `ForEach` to `Text(source.map {$0.text }.joined(separator: "\n\n"))`

Updates:
Here I used one label and it works for me :) but anyway it looks like workaround.

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var textFruit = ""
@State var rect: CGRect = .zero

var stringArray = ["Apples\n\n", "Pears\n\n", "Strawberries\n\n", "Kiwi\n\n", "Blueberries\n\n"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
                ScrollView {
                    Text(textFruit)
                    .border(.yellow)
                    .id("bottom")
                    .onChange(of: textFruit) { value in
                        print(rect.origin.y)
                        if rect.origin.y > 750 { // after 750 we should start to scroll
                            scrollReader.scrollTo("bottom")

                        }
                    }
                    .border(.red)

                    Spacer()
                        .rectReader($rect)
                        .border(.green)
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                if let element = stringArray.randomElement() {
                    textFruit += element
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Add Word")
            })

            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

}

extension View {
func rectReader(_ binding: Binding, _ space: CoordinateSpace = .global) -> some View {
GeometryReader { (geometry) -> Color in
let rect = geometry.frame(in: space)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
binding.wrappedValue = rect
}
return .clear
}
}
}

Comment: ForEach creating a series of Text views doesn't help me, because I'm trying to build a single string. The example you provided mapping source to a single text does work, as long as the user scrolls to the bottom of the ScrollView manually the first time. Thereafter, the button works as expected. This also seems like really odd behavior for the scrollTo.

Comment: oh I see. It seems this is content size problem. We are trying to scroll content but in the same tile we don't have it.

Comment: I get the same behavior with this second solution. If I scroll to the bottom manually and then keep adding "fruits" it works, but only after manually intervening. Check this out though, if you use this as the stringArray your solution doesn't seem to work at all:  var stringArray = ["Apples\n\n", "Pears\n\n", "Strawberries\n\n", "Steve ", "Kiwi\n\n", "Blueberries\n\n", "Alice ", "Fred ", "Betty "]. Basically, as soon as a word is added on the same line, scrollTo stops working. Tried change your rect.origin to look for x or y and also rect.size width and height. Print fires, but no scroll To